# Can't install PHP using Homebrew on macOS

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install PHP on macOS using Homebrew (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/php), but every time I get the following error:

```
Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "php".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

And when using `brew search php` I can only find phpstorm and eclipse-php.
How come I can't find or install PHP on macOS using Homebrew?
Thanks in advance!

Side note: I have already updated Homebrew to the latest version and checked the formulae on GitHub, last commit was 6 days ago https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/php.rb

Comment: what does ``brew doctor`` command print?

Comment: try this https://githubmemory.com/repo/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/77629

Comment: Thanks your last links managed to fix it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posting the answer from https://githubmemory.com/repo/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/77629 in case it gets deleted/removed.

**Your core tap is missing. Do:**

```
rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
brew tap homebrew/core
brew update
```

*All due credits to the original poster. :)*